# Real time notifications in AWS (server less)

Tags: amazon-web-services, vue.js, notifications

I'm implementing real time notification for my web app in AWS built in typescript and Vue. The application consists of an an RDS instance(mysql) node.js lambda functions (for the backend), and s3 for the app.

My question is what is the best way to handle notifications being created on the db for a user (this includes knowing when a notification has been created and sending it to the client)? An example of this is say I have a notifications table in the db, and whenever something the user needs to be notified about gets added to that table. From what I can find I have two options 1. Use Web sockets with API gateway and have lambda functions to communicate back and forth with the client or 2. use AWS IoT (https://www.serverless.com/blog/serverless-notifications-on-aws).

The problem with the first option is how does lambda know when a notification has been added to the notifications table on the RDS instance, because I can't have a lambda function just continually polling the db (defeats the purpose of using lambda).

If you have a better solution to handling real time notifications for web apps ( Vuejs) then please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

Please disregard my question I think I've worked out the solution.

-Each time someone makes a change on the db etc for notifications (which happens via lambda) it will also trigger another lambda function to notify the user of the change that has been made.

A user will use web sockets to keep a connection open with API gateway and the lambda function will then look for the connection ID and send the new notification to the user.

Please let me know if this does not make sense and I will elaborate further. This is also probably not the best solution but I'm just a junior and my boss wants it done and this is makes sense to me.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to take a look at [DynamoDB streams](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Streams.Lambda.html).

It's a more elegant solution than having two Lambdas. Each insertion in the DB will trigger the Lambda. Then you would need to update the front end accordingly.

There's a tutorial detailing the integration between DynamoDB streams and Lambda [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Streams.Lambda.Tutorial.html).

Depending on the needs of scaling of your application, Kinesis can be a great option as well. Basically, if you are using just DynamoDB streams, you will be calling Lambda one time per request, and that will be a problem if you are getting a lot of requests. Kinesis solves that issue, as you can feed data from the DynamoDB into Kinesis instead of Lambda, and then call Lambda each X seconds with the collected data and operate on the aggregation of requests in just one call.

[Here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Streams.KCLAdapter.html) is some info regarding that integration.

Remember to take into account the extra cost of using those services.

Comment: Thanks for your answer unfortunately I have to use mysql so I can't use dynamo db, but the solution you provided is much more elegant.